# What is the difference between share-on-Facebook and Facebook-like?

Tags: facebook, sharing

What is the difference between share-on-Facebook and Facebook-like? I see both of them in many pages. Which one to use? What are the factor for choosing?

Answer (score 3):

Sharing something on Facebook from a separate website will allow you to add a comment before it posts anything to your newsfeed. It will also show a small preview of the page you shared on your friends' newsfeeds.

Liking something from a website does not allow you to make any comment on it as you share it, and it only shows up in your friends' newsfeeds as " likes X"

[Here](http://blog.ninanet.com/2010/05/13/facebook-share-vs-like) is a good comparison of the two